How create a decorator to get output information about the input and output arguments in python?
I have this function with the decorator validate_numeric to validate if the input arguments of a function are numeric (types int or float).
If any of the arguments passed to the function are not numeric, it should return a message: The input arguments must be numeric and stop execution. Otherwise, it should execute the decorated function normally.

def validate_numeric(func): # Decorator
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        for arg in args:
            if not isinstance(arg, (int, float)):
                return "The input arguments must be numeric."
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            if not isinstance(value, (int, float)):
                return "The input arguments must be numeric."
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@validate_numeric
def sum(a, b): # Return the sum of two numbers
    return a + b


print(sum(1, 2))
print(sum(1, "2"))
print(sum(a=1, b="a"))
print(sum(a=1, b=3.4))

it is working fine, this is the output:
3
The input arguments must be numeric.
The input arguments must be numeric.
4.4

now, i need Keep the previous code and create an additional decorator named debug.
This will let us get some information on the execution of the function without having to add print all over the body of the function.
This decorator should simply output information about the input and output arguments. It should indicate both the positional and keyword arguments passed to the function and the output before returning it.
Use the following test cases:
@debug
def sum(a, b):
    """Return the sum of two numbers."""
    return a + b

sum(1, 2)
sum(a=1, b=2)
sum(1, "a")

Your result should look like this:
**********
Positional arguments: 1,2
There are no keyword arguments
Result: 3
**********
There are no positional arguments
Keyword arguments: a=1,b=2
Result: 3
**********
Positional arguments: 1,a
There are no keyword arguments
Result: The input arguments must be numeric

I try to create   this
def debug(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(f"Function name: {func.__name__}")
        print(f"Arguments: {args}")
        print(f"Keyword arguments: {kwargs}")
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


def validate_numeric(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        for arg in args:
            if not isinstance(arg, (int, float)):
                return "The input arguments must be numeric."
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            if not isinstance(value, (int, float)):
                return "The input arguments must be numeric."
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


@debug
def sum(a, b): #Return the sum of two numbers
    return a + b

#1st case
print(sum(1,  2))
#2nd case
print(sum(a=1, b=2))
#3rd case
print(sum(1,"a"))

but i got and error with the 3rd case, i got this error:

Decorator @debug
********************************************************************************
Function name: sum
Arguments: (1, 2)
Keyword arguments: {}
3
********************************************************************************
Function name: sum
Arguments: ()
Keyword arguments: {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
3
********************************************************************************
Function name: sum
Arguments: (1, 'a')
Keyword arguments: {}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../task-2.py", line 40, in <module>
    print(sum(1,"a"))
  File ".../task-2.py", line 14, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File ".../task-2.py", line 32, in sum
    return a + b
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

The output must be like this:

**********
Positional arguments: 1,2
There are no keyword arguments
Result: 3
**********
There are no positional arguments
Keyword arguments: a=1,b=2
Result: 3
**********
Positional arguments: 1,a
There are no keyword arguments
Result: The input arguments must be numeric


You never applied the @validate_numeric decorator to the function, try using it after @debug.

you write that def sum(a, b): return a + b implies that a and b must be numeric, but you could just as well provide strings for a and b, or any other type that implements __add__

Moreover, consider using functools.wraps.

If you want your decorator to infer the types of arguments and return value from type hints, you probably want to use typing.get_type_hints

Thanks, @metatoaster i used the @validate_numeric decorator after@debug decorator but i forget mention that the output still is not like taht must be: i got know on 3er. case only The input arguments must be numeric the Positional arguments: and the keyword arguments are misigng: # Task 2 - Decorator @debug
Output:
Function name: sum
Arguments: (1, 2)
Keyword arguments: {}
3
*
Function name: sum
Arguments: ()
Keyword arguments: {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
3
The input arguments must be numeric.<-3er. case.

This is because the location of the decorators sometimes matters. And of your comment, I realize that's what you're doing now:
@validate_numeric
@debug
def sum(a, b): # Return the sum of two numbers
    return a + b

"Under the hood" it will be like this:
sum = validate_numeric(debug(sum))

Now after calling your decorated function sum, the first thing to call is the function - validate_numeric, in the third case it will simply check that the arguments are not numeric and return immediately the result - "The input arguments must be numeric.", without further calling the function debug. In order for this to work, you should change the order of the decorators to this:
@debug
@validate_numeric
def sum(a, b): # Return the sum of two numbers
    return a + b

Which would actually look like this:
sum = debug(validate_numeric(sum))

If you now run your code - the output will match your expectations:
Function name: sum
Arguments: (1, 2)
Keyword arguments: {}
3
Function name: sum
Arguments: ()
Keyword arguments: {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
3
Function name: sum
Arguments: (1, 'a')
Keyword arguments: {}
The input arguments must be numeric.

Other than that, there are a few tips. A good practice when writing decorators is to use an additional @wraps decorator from the built-in functools module to save the metadata of the function being decorated. For example:
from functools import wraps


def deco(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        ...

    return wrapper


@deco
def some_func():
    """Doc string"""


print(some_func.__name__)  # some_func
print(some_func.__doc__)  # Doc string

In the opposite case, without using the @wraps decorator, you will lose the original function name and documentation string:
def deco(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        ...

    return wrapper


@deco
def some_func():
    """Doc string"""


print(some_func.__name__)  # wrapper
print(some_func.__doc__)  # None

Also, try not to name your functions similar to the functions that are available by default in python. Like the sum function in your case, this can sometimes lead you to unexpected results. For such cases, if there is a conflict, use _ after the function name - sum_ .
